# Images are not showing good in a div

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image

I am making a wordpress website with the theme Zerif Pro. The website is http://www.solids-solutions.com/zerif/
Under the header images you have the our foucus sections. In that sections are the images not that great. It is only good in google chrome because i use the zoom: 0.64; in css. But it only works in chrome. Can someone please help me.

Comment: When I clicked on your link, an "Access dined" error did occure.

Comment: the link which you have provided is not working.

Comment: Provide code snippets and screen shots if you want any reliable feedback.

Comment: The website is now working. It is for a company so i disabled all the ip. Now you can see the website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is about cross browser issues right?

Try this..

```
zoom: 0.64; /* IE */
-moz-transform: scale(0.64); /* Firefox */
-o-transform: scale(0.64); /* Opera */
-webkit-transform: scale(0.64); /* Safari And Chrome */
transform: scale(0.64); /* Standard Property */
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but it does not work well.

Comment: Set your image backgrounds width to 100%.. Try this code `.our-focus-widget-image {background-size: 100% 100% !important; transform: scale(1.1);}`

Comment: Works like a cham, Thank you so much